# Why shouldn't a precooked pie be frozen?

Tags: freezing, pie

I bought a Selection brand strawberry pre-cooked pie. I just read the instructions on the pie and just realized it was pre-cooked but it says to not freeze the pie. Unfortunately, I froze it right away when I got home because I couldn't find my reading glasses and didn't read the instructions.

Are any health concerns here? If not, what could the reason be for being warned not to freeze the pie?

Comment: What are the instructions on the pie other than "do not freeze"?

Answer (score 5):

Generally, these warnings are for food *quality* reasons, not for safety reasons.

Assuming this is a fresh strawberry pie, I'd guess that - because strawberries don't bake or freeze particularly well - if you freeze the pie, the fresh strawberries will turn to mush and not taste very good, particularly if you try to bake it to heat it up.

Freezing something should never make it *unsafe* to consume... freezing is a preserving method.

Answer (score 0):

It's not for safety reasons that the label says not to freeze. It says that because they anticipate that freezing the pie will have a negative effect on quality. I'm guessing that freezing will make the pie mushy.